# Orthogonal polynomials with respect to weighted inner product

Tags: regression, polynomial, matrix-decomposition

Recently I have posted a question on SO, but maybe here is better place to ask.
So, I have data and I want to fit polynomial of order $k$ orthogonal with respect to **weighted** inner product of functions:
$$
\left<f, g\right> = \sum_{j}^{n} \omega_j f(x_j) g(x_j)
$$
Here $w_j$ is a vector of weights (constants assigned to each of $n$ points $x_j$).

When all $w_j = 1$ we have *ordinary* euclidean inner product $\left<f, g\right> = \sum f(x_j) g(x_j)$ and we can do it by [**QR decomposition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) $V_{ij}$:

$$ V = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 &... & x_1^k \\ 
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 &... & x_2^k\\ 
... & ... & ... & ...\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & ... & x_n^k
\end{bmatrix}.$$
QR decomposition:
$$
V = QR, \quad QQ^T = 1.
$$
So the columns of $Q$ are orthogonal to each other with respect to ordinary euclidean inner product $\left<f, g\right> = \sum f(x_j) g(x_j)$.

**My question is**: How can I use **QR** decomposition to get the matrix, whose columns are orthogonal  with respect to **weighted** inner product of functions?

I was thinking about introducing diagonal weights matrix

$$ W = \begin{bmatrix} 
\omega_1 & 0 & ...\\ 
0 & \omega_2 & ...\\ 
... & ... & ...
\end{bmatrix}$$
and applying QR decomposition to matrix $\sqrt{W}V$:

$$
\sqrt{W}V = \widetilde{Q}R, \quad \widetilde{Q}\widetilde{Q}^T = 1
$$
and after that defining Q as 
$$
Q = \left(\sqrt{W}\right)^{-1}\widetilde{Q},
$$
but I haven't succeeded proving that and maybe it's wrong.

Could anyone help me? I know how to generate such polynomial recursively, but I want to know if one could somehow use QR decomposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Not sure about the QR decomposition</strike> (see edit), but I found a way to do it with an eigendecomposition (derivation below).

### Formulating the problem

Let $n \times (k+1)$ matrix $V$ be the Vandermonde matrix, as defined in the original question. We want to factor $V$ into a product of two matrices: 1) An $n \times (k+1)$ matrix $A$, where $A_{ij}$ contains the value of the $j$th orthogonal polynomial evaluated at the $i$th data point, and 2) A $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ matrix $B$:

$$A B = V$$

The columns of $A$ must be orthogonal in the sense defined in the original question. That is:

$$A^T W A = I$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $W$ is a diagonal $n \times n$ matrix containing the weights. The solution below actually applies for any symmetric, positive definite $W$; it doesn't have to be diagonal.

### Solution

One possible solution is:

$$A = V U \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}} \quad
B = \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} U^T$$

where $U \Lambda U^T$ is the eigendecomposition of $V^T W V$

The solution is actually only specified up to unitary transformations (i.e. rotations and sign flips), so there are infinitely many. That is, given a solution $(A,B)$ and any matrix $M$ where $M^T M = I$, then $(A M, M^T B)$ is also a solution.

### Derivation

Since $AB = V$ we can write:

$$(A B)^T W (A B)
\enspace = \enspace B^T A^T W A B
\enspace = \enspace V^T W V$$

Since $A^T W A = I$ this simplifies to:

$$B^T B = V^T W V$$

Let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix containing the eigenvectors of $V^T W V$ on the columns, and let diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ contain the corresponding eigenvalues. So $U \Lambda U^T = V^T W V$. Then a solution to the above equation is:

$$B = \Lambda^\frac{1}{2} U^T$$

Plugging this back into $A B = V$ gives:

$$A \Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}} U^T = V$$

Since $U$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal, we can solve for $A$ by right-multiplying both sides by $U \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}$:

$$A = V U \Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

### Edit: Solution based on QR decomposition

The OP proposed the following solution (I've changed some variable names): Let $\tilde{Q} \tilde{R}$ be the QR decomposition of $W^{\frac{1}{2}} V$. Then:

$$A = W^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{Q}$$

Here's a proof that the columns are orthogonal:

$$A^T W A
\tag{This must equal the identity matrix}$$

$$= \tilde{Q}^T (W^{-\frac{1}{2}})^T W W^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{Q}
\tag{Substitute in expression for $A$}$$

$$= \tilde{Q}^T W^{-\frac{1}{2}} W W^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{Q}
\tag{$W$ is symmetric}$$

$$= \tilde{Q}^T \tilde{Q}
\tag{$W^{-\frac{1}{2}} W W^{-\frac{1}{2}} = I$}$$

$$= I
\tag{By definition of the QR decomposition}$$

We can find the corresponding $B$ by solving $A B = V$, which gives:

$$B = \tilde{Q}^T W^{\frac{1}{2}} V$$

Therefore, this is also a valid solution. The solution above (based on the eigendecomposition; call it $A_{eig}$) and the OP's solution (based on the QR decomposition; call it $A_{QR}$) are related as:

$$A_{eig} = A_{QR} M
\quad B_{eig} = M^T B_{QR}
\quad \text{where} \quad
M = \tilde{Q}^T W^{\frac{1}{2}} V U L^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

One can show that $M^T M = I$, so this is a unitary transformation (see the note above about infinitely many solutions).

Comment: You can do this with modified gram schmidt

Comment: @davefournier Yes, it seems one could use a version of modified Gram-Schmidt that works in general inner product spaces, rather than the typical Euclidean version. But, the OP asked for a non-recursive solution, which Gram-Schmidt wouldn't satisfy.

Comment: user20160 Not sure why modified gram schmidt is "recursive", but given that why is it more recursive than QR?

Comment: @user20160 Thank you for your detailed answer. I checked that it indeed provides us orthogonal (as defined in post) matrix. As you mentioned, the form of matrix specified up to rotations. Since I want in the case when all weights are equal to 1 the same result as standard poly() function with QR -- what can I do for it? Could you give a hint how to obtain corresponding rotation?

Comment: @davefournier The idea was to use already built-in functions. I've rewrote standard R's poly() function in python, which uses built in numpy QR function. But I have to use weighted scalar product for my data. As far as I know, QR decomposition in numpy uses modified Gram-Schmidt, but I'm not confident enough that I'm able to rewrite it with weights efficiently enough. So I was trying to use QR :) By "recurrence" I mean equation , that allows to obtain \phi_k+1 from \phi_k and \phi_k-1.

Comment: @xxxxx I took a look again at the solution you proposed based on the QR decomposition. See my edited answer for a proof that it works, and that it's equivalent to the eigendecomposition method (up to rotation & sign flips). So, you should be fine using QR if you want to match the output of poly(). Of course, there's no 'privileged basis' so any unitary transformation is as valid as any other.